# Unit testing Rcpp code in a package

Tags: r, unit-testing, rcpp

I have some C++ code in a package that I want to unit test and I don't want to export to R. I've seen:

[Unit tests for code in the /src folder of an R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779583/unit-tests-for-code-in-the-src-folder-of-an-r-package)

and the code I want to test falls into the second category:

> Or you consider your C code to be more standalone, in which case you could use one of a bazillion unit testing frameworks for C.

If one wants to test from C++ (not in using a R framework) what is the best way to setup the test suite? Do you put your C++ tests in `tests/` and then have a C++ program with a main somewhere, or do you write a driver function to execute all the C++ tests and then call it from R?

I imagine it is probably a good idea to have the tests be automated by `R CMD check` as well, which I'm not clear on how to automate using the R package framework.

Comment: I suggest you narrow down your question into a programming one. Note also that these kind of questions have a high chance of being closed as "looking for a tool" or "opinion based".

Comment: If you want the tests to be run by `R CMD check`, you might consider adding a `configure` or `cleanup` script that invokes some other script running those test files. See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup for more details.

Comment: @KevinUshey, thanks! This will definitely work! I was hoping there was already some canonical way to do this without writing additional scripts, but doesn't seem that way.

Comment: I agree -- but unfortunately, the built-in facilities for `R CMD check` only accommodate unit testing of `R` code. I think using a `configure` / `cleanup` script is still the best way to go, though. (Or a custom makefile if you are really adventurous...)

Answer (score 5):

I do not follow:

- Either it *is* [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) code, but you *do not want to expose it to R*: The moment you wan to *expose it to the (R) unit tests* (in the packaging framework) you do though.
- Or it is just a question of picking one of (a great many) C++ unit testing framework like the [Boost Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) library, or the [Google C++ Testing library](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/), or ... --- none of which has been ported to R "as such"

Can you clarify your question a little more?

Maybe you just want to express your C++ code in a way that lets [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) call it *from only the unit tests* so that you get results you can then test via one of popular R unit testing frameworks.  In which case the answer may be very similar to what any one of the (currently) 276 Rcpp-using packages on CRAN do as many *do* in fact use unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Dirk. I've updated my question -- please let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Rcpp has a pretty well-defined scope. What you want here seems to be outside of that scope, at least to my understanding.  Rcpp may still help you as I outlined, but you in essence have a completely different problem ("how do I ship and test a C++ library") which ex ante has nothing to with R.